# Is there a zipWith function for arrays?

Tags: haskell

I have two arrays of equal size and I want to combine them element-wise. What is the best way to do this? The `array` package doesn't seem to provide a `zipWith` equivalent function.

I'm reluctant to make my own function because the main way I can think of doing this is to convert back and forth with lists. I care about speed and I assume this way is not the most efficient way.

Comment: Maybe you could use [`vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) instead?

Comment: That might be the best way to go. Can `vector` types have 2D indexing? `array` types have convenient indexing.

Comment: No, vectors can only be indexed by `Int` as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use [repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.3/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html). Might get some performance benefit from the parallelism as well, should you care about it.

Option 2: just get indices using `bounds`. I would suggest avoiding list comprehensions in general; though the other answer uses them correctly in this case, it may be worthwhile to get in the habit of doing the right thing.

```
zipWithArr f xs ys = listArray (bounds xs) $ fmap (liftA2 f (xs !) (ys !)) (range (bounds xs))
```

The reason that this works is that Haskell's lists are lazy, and we can generally treat them as control structures (due to various optimizations), though we can *not* treat them as containers. Moreover, GHC evaluates an expression at most once per lambda, so in general you do not need to worry that this will be done inefficiently.

Comment: Why avoid list comprehensions?

Comment: Because list comprehensions can introduce incomplete pattern matches that -Wall doesn't catch.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to cook one up yourself:

```
zipWithA f xs ys = listArray (bounds xs) [f (xs ! i) (ys ! i) | i <- range (bounds xs)]
```

Comment: Is there a performance hit from converting back from a list? It seems like an indirect way.

Comment: @user668074 As always with these questions, you have to ask "performance hit compared to _what_?". The most obvious alternative seems to be making a mutable array, looping over indices, writing in the results, and then freezing; it seems to me the cost of taking steps in the loop is going to be basically identical to the cost of walking down this list. More realistically I expect the repeated bounds checking (shared by both approaches) is going to be the more noticeable cost. But if you care a lot... take some measurements!